# Причины возникновения ошибки the requested address is not valid in its context в корпоративной сети

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Создаю tcpclient, отправляю через него http запрос на другую корпоративную машину. Получаю ошибку в заголовке. Тот же самый запрос через httpclient отрабатывает и возвращает 200. Нашел информацию по теме https://www.techinpost.com/the-requested-address-is-not-valid-in-its-context/, но не уверен, что оно применимо.

**Добавлено**
Я использую код отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/35533927/2208894
Я заменил преамбулу подключения на код с форума от Ричарда Блума, и теперь wireshark отображает отправленный запрос и ответ с кодом 200:

```
Socket sock = new  Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
  IPEndPoint ipep = new  IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4"),1234);
  sock.Connect(ipep);
  var stream = new NetworkStream(sock);
```

Теперь проблема в том, что приложение зависает на строке:`await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);`

Comment: как вы создаете tcpclient и как отправляете запрос? покажите код, пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил код. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: в преведенном коде вы не отправляете запрос, а сразу ожидаете результат, и сервер от вас ждет запрос, возможно в это проблема

Comment: Там же есть stream.WriteAsync.